# No empty constructor when create a service

Tags: java, android

I am struggling with this error:

> 08-08 11:42:53.179: E/AndroidRuntime(20288): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.localnotificationtest.ReminderService; no empty constructor

I don't understand why this error occurs.

I am trying to appear notification at specific time and after searching for a time i found this [old stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7540724/1250370). I tried everything but my code gives error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int mHour, mMinute;
    ReminderService reminderService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reminderService = new ReminderService("ReminderService");

        TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =  new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker v, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.YEAR);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            long timeInMills = c.getTimeInMillis();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMills, pendingIntent);
        }
    };

}
```

and here is my ReminderService code:

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {

    public ReminderService(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Local Notification Ticker")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Local Notification")
            .setContentText("This is content text.");
         Notification n = builder.getNotification();

         nm.notify(1, n);
    }

}
```

and here is my manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.localnotificationtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="ReminderService"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Am I missing some code?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You need to add an empty constructor to your class **i.e. one that takes no arguments:**

```
public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
}
```

Explanation from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#IntentService(java.lang.String)):

The `name` is used to name the worker thread.

***NOTE***: this is only applicable to intent service.

Comment: Bold that **Constructor with no argument**

Answer (score 44):

If you have your Service declared as an **Inner Class / Nested Class**, you also need to make the class **static**

Without that you´ll get the error even if your constructor is correct

> **Explanation**
>
> The reason for that is, you can only instantiate inner classes in the
>   context of the outer class, so you would need to create an instance of
>   the outer class first.
>
> Declaring your inner class static makes it independent from its outer class

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: I don´t know if it is documented anywhere, but if you want to instantiate inner non static classes, the outer class must be instantiated first. Now if you start a service, the instance is created by the system, which won´t know that it has to make an instance from the outer class first, so it will crash. But the error is really misleading in that case. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 32):

Declare a **default no-argument constructor** for **IntentService**

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {
    public ReminderService() {
      super("ReminderService");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the **default no-argument constructor** to your **ReminderService** class. This is only implicitly added if you don't write a constructor of your own (which you have). See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html