# No empty constructor

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am trying to use a remote service to build a BlueTooth Chat (like the one of the Android Samples). But since my last modifications, the application does not start and the log shows the error `no empty constructor` for my service. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859403/no-empty-constructor-when-create-a-service) but I cant add any empty constructor. There must be something I do wrong, or maybe it doesnt work for remote services.

This is my constructor :

```
public RemoteService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Why can't you add a empty constructor?

Comment: You have to add a no argument constructor

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public RemoteService() {
    super();
}
```

Unless your business rules states you can't really have an empty constructor. Then you're calling for a `new RemoteService()` somewhere, when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide default constructor as the service demands a default constructor and then you can use parametrized constructor as you have done.

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {

   ----------------------------
    public ReminderService() // Need to add the default constructor
    {
      super("ReminderService"); // Calling the super constructor
    }

   public RemoteService(Context context, Handler handler) //Then use your own constructor
   {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
  }
  ----------------------------------

}
```

Try this one and let me know if you still have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but meanwhile, someone helped me and cleaned the code, removing the constructor and doing some other things, but I didn't understand everything.

I am sorry I can't explain exactly what was wrong, but I can say that a non argument constructor was generating errors.