# How to make notification push automatically without click any button?

Tags: android, notifications

I have developed one application that required notification displayed to the user. So I already search on how to create a notification and made it display automatically by setting date and time without using any button to push the notification.Anyone can help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7540949/5308778) to create future notification on particular date and time

Comment: You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify your user. or if you want to local notification then use service and Broadcast receiver to show notification.

Comment: Easiest solution would probably be the JobScheduler API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html